# PHPImageWorkShop Library showing blank page

Tags: php, apache

I am using PHPImageWorkShop, I have been trying to find out why the library returns blank page.

```
require_once 'PHPImageWorkshop/ImageWorkshop.php';

use PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop;

$layer = ImageWorkshop::initFromPath('img1.jpg');

var_dump($layer)
```

I tested the script on Godaddy VPS, It's showing a blank page but shows the `var_dump` contents on a shared Godaddy hosting account.

Increased the `memory_limit` on the php.ini to 512M and the problem persists. Please, what other setup should i consider before using PHPImageWorkShop on Godaddy VPS. Thanks.